# SQL sum function - how to sum and still include the non-summed columns

Tags: sql-server

I want to sum columns by startDate. There are 3,213 rows.

I want and expect only to get 51 rows.

If I use this, I get the 3,213 but not summed up per StartDate. Hence the 51 rows.

```
SELECT SwitchID as S,
       PortIndex as P,
       SUM(BandwidthIn) as sum1,
       SUM(BandwidthOut) as sum2,
       SUM(BandwidthInMbps) as sum3,
       SUM(BandwidthOutMbps) as sum4,
       StartDate,
       EndDate,
       'day' as D
FROM dbo.BandwidthLogCalculatedTest
WHERE ( StartDate < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME) )
AND (EntryType = 'Second' )
GROUP BY StartDate,
         EndDate,
         SwitchID,
         PortIndex
```

For example (showing 3 of the 3,213 rows):

```
S P sum1 sum2 sum3 sum4 StartDate               EndDate                 D
8 1 2184 821  0.00 0.00 2016-08-29 17:00:30.810 2016-08-29 17:01:00.827 day
8 2 0    2    0.00 0.00 2016-08-29 17:00:30.810 2016-08-29 17:01:00.827 day
8 3 621 598   0.00 0.00 2016-08-29 17:00:30.810 2016-08-29 17:01:00.827 day
```

If use this, I get the correct number of rows, but without the Switchid, 
PortIndex, StartDate, Enddate and 'day' designation which i also need.

```
SELECT  SUM(BandwidthIn) as BandwidthIn,
        SUM(BandwidthOut) as BandwidthOut,
        SUM(BandwidthInMbps) as BandwidthInMbps,
        SUM(BandwidthOutMbps) as BandwidthOutMbps,
        'day' as EngtryType
FROM dbo.BandwidthLogCalculatedTest
WHERE ( StartDate < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME) )
AND ( EntryType = 'Second' )
GROUP BY StartDate,
         EndDate
```

For example (showing 2 of the 51 rows):

```
BandwidthIn BandwidthOut  BandwidthInMbps BandwidthOutMbps EntryType
429688      625227        98.00           150.00           day
497928      688985        113.00          167.00           day
```

Comment: Are your StartDate and EndDate (declared as `DATETIME`) have different hh, mm seconds and mmseconds, and you want your group by date (day) without consideration of hhmmssms ? Then, it it is the case, you should use a way to remove time info from your StartDate and EndDate (eg : `select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, StartDate()), 0)` ?

Comment: Yes they are datetime.

Comment: So, would you precise whether you are considering hhmmssmmm in your group by, or you only want to group by DDMMYYYY (Day format, without time ) in theStartDate and EndDate ?

Comment: I want all columns as they are defined. I 'm basically rolling them up (summing) those numeric columns. So I do want the datetime. (including the hhmmssmmm)

Comment: The SUM is processed for each rupture occured on StartDate,
EndDate, SwitchID, and PortIndex (mentionned in the `GROUP BY` clause).
This is meaning that you have different values in SwitchID, and PortIndex and can not include in your `SELECT` .. `GROUP BY` statement to get the 51 lines

Comment: As I look closer, yes you are correct. I want to group by just the day and not the time portion hhmmssmss. I used your suggestion on removing the time info. I had to do it on the 2 date columns as well as the 2 in the GROUP BY. I get the expected number of rows now, however the results do not include the the original values in the StartDate and EndDate.

Comment: To explain this further, I have posted again under: SQL sum function - how to sum up and still include the original values.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the output you're expecting doesn't match the purpose you are intending.  That purpose seems to be summing bandwidth by day, in which case grouping by `Switch_id` and `PortIndex` is going to split your data in ways you don't want unless each `StartDate`/`EndDate` combination has only one value each of `Switch_id` and `PortIndex`.

If each `StartDate`/`EndDate` combination had only one value each of `Switch_id` and `PortIndex` your first query would return the 51 rows your expect, and you could select `Switch_id` and `PortIndex`.  However, if each `StartDate`/`EndDate` combination has multiple `Switch_id` and `PortIndex` values you'll get many more rows since it's looking for unique combinations of all four fields.

If I'm understanding your intent correctly you'd change your first query to group by just `StartDate` and `EndDate`.  Since you'd be summing across `Switch_id` and `PortIndex` values, you cannot select those variables.

Code would be:

```
SELECT 
       SUM(BandwidthIn) as sum1,
       SUM(BandwidthOut) as sum2,
       SUM(BandwidthInMbps) as sum3,
       SUM(BandwidthOutMbps) as sum4,
       StartDate,
       EndDate,
       'day' as D
FROM dbo.BandwidthLogCalculatedTest
WHERE ( StartDate < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME) )
AND (EntryType = 'Second' )
GROUP BY StartDate,
         EndDate
```